# Smooth mixed hodge modules - representations of fundamental group?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, hodge-theory, d-modules, perverse-sheaves

I do not know much about mixed Hodge modules. I would like to ask: Let $X$ be a smooth connected algebraic complex variety, with a chosen point. Could one describe smooth mixed Hodge modules on $X$ as some representations of the fundamental group? Of course, I ask because I have in mind other cases - for example, smooth perverse sheaves will be the same as representations of the fundamental group in finite-dimensional vector spaces.

Thank you,
Sasha

Comment: My expectation is that there will be no positive answer to your question. The data of a smooth (pure) Hodge module (aka variation of Hodge structure) involves a filtration on the holomorphic sections of the underlying vector bundle. This filtration is not flat, but rather satisfies the Griffiths transversality condition $\nabla \mathcal F^n \subseteq \mathcal F^{n-1}\otimes \Omega^1$. It doesn't look like it is possible to express these data and conditions in terms of the monodromy.

Comment: The answer is pretty much what Sam & Dan are saying. While I don't want to self-advertise, you can take a look at http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/0902.4252 for a bit more info.

Comment: It is important to specify whether one considers an integral, real or complex mixed Hodge structure. For example, the integral lattice in a variation of pure Hodge structures of weight 1 is the same as a family of smooth curves which can be interesting (even over a disc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is no. The best you can say is the following: there is a functor rat from mixed Hodge modules to perverse sheaves, and for smooth $X$, $\mathrm{rat}(\mathscr M)$ is a local system  iff $\mathscr M$ is smooth. But a smooth mixed Hodge module contains more information than its underlying local system (think about the case when $X$ is a point!). The precise extra data you need on a local system to define a mixed Hodge module is that of an admissible variation of mixed Hodge structure, see Steenbrink and Zucker: Variation of mixed Hodge structure I.

Edit: On second thought, maybe I want to change my answer in a different direction. The category of smooth mixed Hodge modules on $X$ is neutral tannakian, with the basepoint you wisely fixed providing the fiber functor. Then such mixed Hodge modules are in fact the same as representations of some horribly complicated pro-algebraic group. Maybe this is not the kind of answer you were after, but there it is.